# jquery REGEX validation for letters and Numbers onlyu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can any body tell me what is the Regex validation to use my textbox should take only letters and Numbers?

```
  var BLIDRegExpression = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;

    if (BLIDRegExpression.test(BLIDIdentier)) {
        alert('The BLID Identifier may only consist of letters or numbers and must be exactly five characters long.');
        return false;
    }
```

I am using this one but its not working. can anybody tell me.

Thanks

Comment: whats the value for BLIDIdentier?

Comment: by the way, you can use /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}$/ to check that the string is exactly 5 characters long too, if you want (to test the second half of your error message too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.test` returns true if the string matches. I think you want:

```
var BLIDRegExpression = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}$/; // {5} adds the requirement that the string be 5 chars long

if (!BLIDRegExpression.test(BLIDIdentier)) {
    alert('The BLID Identifier may only consist of letters or numbers and must be exactly five characters long.');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thank you. but when I enter like this a0012 or A0001 still i am getting validation error. it sould not happend right?

Comment: I just tried both in Chrome's console. What browser are you using? Try [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dHsPN/).

Answer (score 1):

Reverse your logic.  `.test()` returns true when it matches, false when it does not match.  You want to execute your `if` statement when it does NOT match.  If you also want it to be required to be exactly 5 characters long, then you can use `{5}` instead of `*` in your regex like this:

```
var BLIDRegExpression = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}$/;

if (!BLIDRegExpression.test(BLIDIdentier)) {
    alert('The BLID Identifier may only consist of letters or numbers and must be exactly five characters long.');
    return false;
}
```